# Creating a custom class and using it as an object/list

Tags: java, class

I've created a custom class called Person.
Now I want to use the person class the same way you can with a String or int class, by turning them into a table when I create a variable with the person class.

```
Person[] persons = new Person[3];
```

But when I do it like this, I get the error: `NullPointerException`.
Is there any way to fix it, so I can use the person class as a list?

This is my person class:

```
class Person{
  //Definerer navn og posisjonen.
  String navn;
  String[] interesser = new String[4];

  //Funksjonen for aa sette navn.
  void settNavn(String navn){
    this.navn = navn;
  }

  //Funksjonen for aa sette interesser.
  void settInteresser(String interesser, int index){
    this.interesser[index] = interesser;
  }

  //Funksjonen for aa hente navnet.
  String hentNavn(){
    return navn;
  }

  //Funksjonen for aa hente interessene.
  String hentInteresser(int index){
    return interesser[index];
  }
}
```

Comment: Umm, this definitely isn't JavaScript.

Comment: @Chris Java are we ?

Comment: The Java motion passes. Next case.

Comment: @Chris: What language is this?  You say `NullPointerException`, so is this Java?  Note: Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You've said you're getting an error, but you haevn't shown the code giving you that error; instead, you've shown code using `String`. `Person[] persons = new Person[5];` works just fine. We can't help you with code we cannot see. Also note that Java and JavaScript are **completely** different languages and environments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating any Person objects. You are creating a Person array with space to hold some Person objects, but I will bet you pounds to pence that you aren't populating that array with a single Person. It is an empty array.

You might write:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[3];
persons[0]=new Person();
```

Now you can call methods of `persons[0]` without getting a `NullPointerException`. Populate the other 2 elements in the array in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for. Using custom classes in this way is still a bit new to me.